# Force Windows Classic Theme for Application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

Hey Guys, I've searched around for this question but couldn't come up with anything.

The Problem:

If a user changes the Color Scheme on their Windows Desktop, it tweaks some functionality in my .net application.

Is there any way for me to FORCE my application to use the Windows Classic Theme, regardless of what the user's theme has been set as?

Thanks!

Comment: What functionality in particular?

Comment: The problem that happens is rather lame.

I have a rich textbox and the vertical scrollbar which shrinks/expands based on the Color Scheme set by the user.  I have an algorithm which parses the text in said textbox into a .rdlc file.  The widths of the actual textbox need to be in sync, but the width of the scrollbar shifts it slightly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio: when you go to your application project's properties, you will find a checkbox *Enable XP Visual Styles*. If you disable that, no theming should be applied to your application. I assume this is equivalent to uncommenting the line of code that user nobugz mentioned.

Comment: Yeah I tried that earlier, but its the Color Scheme (right click desktop -> Properties -> Appearance - > Color Scheme.  The color scheme changes the widths of scrollbars in the application which (unfortunately) effects some things

I'd like to force Windows Standard (instead of Slate etc...)

Comment: Then an alternative would be to figure out the (default) width or height of scrollbars (you can retrieve it via a property somewhere in .NET: `SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth`, or `SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight` respectively). You could use that info to scale your UI elements appropriately.

Comment: I ended up going the route in your comment and it seems to work; thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

At startup set this property on the application object.

```
Application.VisualStyleState = System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleState.NoneEnabled;
```

Comment: Also you have to comment out the enablevisualstyles method

Answer (score 0):

I have done that using DevExpress (http://devexpress.com) controls, they have their own theming engine, and one of the included themes is the Windows Classic one.  The themes even style the window borders, so it is a true complete look and feel control.

As to how to do it natively without a third party control, I do not know.

Specifically, look here for the theming engine in the DevExpress control suite: http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Skins/