# How to prevent visual changes in program, on different versions of windows?

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a program at c#.net 4.0 on a Windows xp. When it's run on windows 7 or vista, some visual changes appear. Some are not important but remeaning parts may be important.

Also on xp itself, a theme can change them in a bad way that not excepted.

How can we prevent or minimize this changes?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962140/enable-disable-aero-in-c-vb-net-or-c-win32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio: when you go to your application project's properties, you will find a checkbox Enable XP Visual Styles.

[credits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104582/force-windows-classic-theme-for-application)

Comment: Will that option make the program interferace constant on all windows versions?

Comment: it should; try it youself - change your windows visual scheme and see